# Can infinite $T_0$ space have less open sets than points?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

It is pretty easy to check, that if $X$ is $T_1$, then it has to have at least as many open sets as points, because every singleton would be closed. On the other hand, if we don't assume anything about $X$, we could choose indiscrete topology and get positive answer.

In the middle, we have $T_0$. My intuition says, that it shouldn't be possible, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proposed by you solution for $T_1$ case works almost the same in $T_0$ case, except you should not focus on singletons, but rather on closures of singletons.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a $T_0$ topological space. Note that two points $x,y$ are [topologically indistinguishable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability) if and only if $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$. Thus in $T_0$ spaces $x=y$ if and only if $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$. This shows that

$$f:X\to \tau$$
$$f(x)=X\backslash\overline{\{x\}}$$

is an injection, regardless of whether $X$ is infinite or not.

Answer (score 3):

**Remark:** This is correct but unnecessarily complicated.

No, it cannot. Suppose $X$ is an infinite set and $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a $T_0$ topological space. Note that $\mathcal{T}$ must be infinite or otherwise this space would have at least some pairs of distinct points that are topologically indistinguishable.

Given any infinite set $A$, let $S(A)$ denote the set of unordered pairs $\{a,b\}$ of distinct points in $A$. Since $A$ is infinite, we have $|A\times A|=|A|$. If $B=A\times A\backslash \{(a,a)\mid a\in A\}$, then there is a canonical surjection $B\to S(A)$ taking an ordered pair $(a,b)$ of distinct points to the unordered pair $\{a,b\}$. One can then extend this to a surjection $A\times A\to S(A)$ to get $|S(A)|\leq |A|$. It's not hard to construct an injection $A\to S(A)$ and so we have $|A|=|S(A)|$.

Applying the previous paragraph to our situation, we have $|X|=|S(X)|$ and $|\mathcal{T}|=|S(\mathcal{T})|$. Thus, to prove that $|X|\leq |\mathcal{T}|$ it suffices to produce an injection $S(X)\to S(\mathcal{T})$.

Define $f:S(X)\to S(\mathcal{T})$ by $f(\{x,y\})=\{X\backslash\overline{x},X\backslash\overline{y}\}$ where $\overline{x}$ denotes the closure of the single-point set $\{x\}$. We'll check some things about $f$ using the following key fact about $T_0$ spaces.

**Fact:** Since $X$ is $T_0$, if we are given $x,y\in X$, then we have $x=y$ if and only if $\overline{x}=\overline{y}$.

**Claim 1:** $f$ is well-defined.

Pf. If $x\neq y$, then because $X$ is $T_0$, $\overline{x}\neq \overline{y}$. Thus $X\backslash\overline{x}\neq X\backslash\overline{y}$ showing the pair $\{X\backslash\overline{x},X\backslash\overline{y}\}$ is an element of $S(\mathcal{T})$. We conclude that $f$ is well-defined.

**Claim 2:** $f$ is injective.

Pf. Suppose $a\neq b$, $x\neq y$ and $f(\{a,b\})=f(\{x,y\})$. Then $\{X\backslash\overline{a},X\backslash\overline{b}\}=\{X\backslash\overline{x},X\backslash\overline{y}\}$ are equal 2-element sets. If $X\backslash\overline{a}=X\backslash\overline{x}$ and $X\backslash\overline{b}=X\backslash\overline{y}$, then $\overline{a}=\overline{x}$ and $\overline{b}=\overline{y}$, giving $a=x$ and $b=y$. If $X\backslash\overline{a}=X\backslash\overline{y}$ and $X\backslash\overline{b}=X\backslash\overline{x}$, the same reasoning gives $a=y$ and $b=x$. Either way, $\{a,b\}=\{x,y\}$. This proves $f$ is injective.

Comment: This is correct but ended up way more complicatd than it needed to be. The other answer should be accepted. The key "fact" is what really gets the job done in the end.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm not used to work with $T_0$ spaces, and I didn't think about the fact you used. With it, it is all immediately clear.